# pd.wide_to_long in python is slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform

I have a dataframe with 55049 rows and 667 columns in it.

> Sample dataframe structure as follows:

```
data = {
    'g1': [1],
    'g2': [2],
    'g3': [3],
    
    'st1_1': [1],
    'st1_2': [1],
    'st1_3': [1],
    'st1_4': [1],
    'st1_5': [5],
    'st1_6': [5],
    'st1_7': [5],
    'st1_8': [5],
    
    'st1_Next_1': [8],
    'st1_Next_2': [8],
    'st1_Next_3': [8],
    'st1_Next_4': [8],
    'st1_Next_5': [9],
    'st1_Next_6': [9],
    'st1_Next_7': [9],
    'st1_Next_8': [9],
    
    'st2_1': [2],
    'st2_2': [2],
    'st2_3': [2],
    'st2_4': [2],
    'st2_5': [2],
    'st2_6': [2],
    'st2_7': [2],
    'st2_8': [2],
    
    'ft_1': [1],
    'ft_2': [0],
    'ft_3': [1],
    'ft_4': [1],
    'ft_5': [1],
    'ft_6': [0],
    'ft_7': [0],
    'ft_8': [1]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

To get my desired output I have the following code where I am using `pd.wide_to_long`

```
ilist = ['g1','g2','g3']
stublist = ['st1','st1_Next','st2','ft']

df_long = pd.wide_to_long(
      df.reset_index(),
      i=['index']+ilist ,
      stubnames= stublist,
      j='j', sep='_').reset_index()

df_long = df_long[df_long['ft']==1]
```

Above code is working in fine with expected results.

> I perfromed this wide_to_long to apply the filter `df_long[df_long['ft']==1]`. which means ft_1 need to apply for all _1, ft_2 for all _2.....and so for all _8.

> Problem is to perform wide_to_long operation it took around 2 mins, Since I have 800+ source files to process the whole process is taking 1600 mins which is quite high.

I Am looking for any alternative suggestions to transpose the data.

I have Tried [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/49174) but didn't work for me with much differenece.

> As @sammywemmy suggested, I have tried below code. But output is missing `st1_Next`.

```py
ilist = ['g1','g2','g3']
stublist = ['st1','st1_Next','st2','ft']


df_pvot = df.pivot_longer(index=ilist,names_to=stublist,names_pattern=stublist)
print(df_pvot)
```

Output is missing st1_Next and data clubbing with st1 Instead of new column.

```
Output:

    g1  g2  g3  st1  st2   ft
0    1   2   3    1  2.0  1.0
1    1   2   3    1  2.0  0.0
2    1   2   3    1  2.0  1.0
3    1   2   3    1  2.0  1.0
4    1   2   3    5  2.0  1.0
5    1   2   3    5  2.0  0.0
6    1   2   3    5  2.0  0.0
7    1   2   3    5  2.0  1.0
8    1   2   3    8  NaN  NaN
9    1   2   3    8  NaN  NaN
10   1   2   3    8  NaN  NaN
11   1   2   3    8  NaN  NaN
12   1   2   3    9  NaN  NaN
13   1   2   3    9  NaN  NaN
14   1   2   3    9  NaN  NaN
15   1   2   3    9  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer), where you pass the new header names to `names_to` and a list of regexes to `names_pattern`:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd

df.pivot_longer(index=ilist,names_to=stublist,names_pattern=stublist)
   g1  g2  g3  st1  st2  ft
0   1   2   3    1    2   1
1   1   2   3    1    2   0
2   1   2   3    1    2   1
3   1   2   3    1    2   1
4   1   2   3    1    2   1
5   1   2   3    1    2   0
6   1   2   3    1    2   0
7   1   2   3    1    2   1
```

Another option is a reshaping of the columns, followed by pd.stack:

```py
reshaped = df.set_index(ilist)
reshaped.columns = reshaped.columns.str.split('_',expand=True).set_names([None,'drop'])
reshaped.stack(level='drop').droplevel('drop').reset_index()
   g1  g2  g3  st1  st2  ft
0   1   2   3    1    2   1
1   1   2   3    1    2   0
2   1   2   3    1    2   1
3   1   2   3    1    2   1
4   1   2   3    1    2   1
5   1   2   3    1    2   0
6   1   2   3    1    2   0
7   1   2   3    1    2   1
```

this is in response to the updated question - the `names_pattern` relies on regexes, and under the hood, `pd.Series.str.contains` and `np.select` is used to extract and pair the columns with the regexes. As such, the regexes have to be crafted properly to match the columns:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor 

# note the inclusion of digits within the regexes
names_pattern = [r'st1_\d+',r'st1_Next',r'st2_\d+', 'ft']

df.pivot_longer(index=ilist,names_to=stublist,names_pattern=names_pattern)
   g1  g2  g3  st1  st1_Next  st2  ft
0   1   2   3    1         8    2   1
1   1   2   3    1         8    2   0
2   1   2   3    1         8    2   1
3   1   2   3    1         8    2   1
4   1   2   3    5         9    2   1
5   1   2   3    5         9    2   0
6   1   2   3    5         9    2   0
7   1   2   3    5         9    2   1
```

You can replicate this using `stack`, this time using `pd.Series.str.rsplit()`, with `n=1`.

```py
reshaped = df.set_index(ilist)
reshaped.columns = (reshaped
                    .columns
                    .str
                    .rsplit('_',n=1,expand=True)
                    .set_names([None, 'drop'])
                   )

reshaped.stack(level='drop').droplevel('drop').reset_index()
   g1  g2  g3  st1  st1_Next  st2  ft
0   1   2   3    1         8    2   1
1   1   2   3    1         8    2   0
2   1   2   3    1         8    2   1
3   1   2   3    1         8    2   1
4   1   2   3    5         9    2   1
5   1   2   3    5         9    2   0
6   1   2   3    5         9    2   0
7   1   2   3    5         9    2   1
```

As long as you understand the pattern your columns have, and adapt your code to them, you should be fine.

Comment: qq: is `pyjanitor` calling `siuba`? Its interesting that R functions are making their way into python. Note that `siuba` contains most R functions and `df.pivot_longer` has been present but few know about it. seems `pyjanitor` is an extension of R's library `janitor`

Comment: @sammywenny I have tried `pd.pivot_longer` quite faster, But the output didn't match. Eg I have two columns st1_1 & st1_Next_1 and expecting two columns in the output but st1_Next is merged st1_1. Only single column st1 output with 16 rows. I have updated the question with the data. Can you help me how to match exactly column names. I have tried `names_sep='_'`. didn't work

Comment: @RoshanNuvvula I will have a look now

Comment: The regexes are greedy, so you have to craft your regexes accordingly to match. I'll update

Comment: @Onyambu no it does not call siuba.yes, pyjanitor is a python version of R's janitor. yes `pivot_longer` is inspired by tidyr's pivot_longer and takes ideas from both pivot_longer and datatable's melt function.

Comment: @sammywemmy I just change the `names_pattern = list(map(lambda x: x +"_[0-9]+", stublist))` with this expression as I have 200+ columns, All working fine. Thanks a ton, this code saved lot of time